# Android: UnknownFormatConversionException when setting dynamic string

Tags: android, string, formatting, resources

I am a bit of a nooby with android and I am trying to set a value inside a dynamic string. The dynamic string is inside the resource file. and I have set it like this:

```
<string name="result">User score is %1$s </string>
```

Then in the code I set the value like this:

```
 String scoreText;
 String scoreNumber ;
 scoreNumber = String.valueOf(ads.get(position).getScoreCount());
 scoreText= String.format(context.getString(R.string.result),scoreNumber);
```

And then I set the the score inside a textview:

```
 viewHolder.scoreTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(scoreText));
```

However for some reasons I am getting this Fatal Exception: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException on this line:

```
scoreText= String.format(context.getString(R.string.result),scoreNumber);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whats similarNumber?

Comment: ops my mistake it should be score number I will fix it.

Comment: getString already use parameters... Use context.getString(R.string.result, scoreNumber) intead if String.format(context.getString(R.string.result),scoreNumber)

Comment: So I should ignore String.format?